# adding a divider between cut,copy and paste in cq:action of editConfig

Tags: content-management-system, aem

Is it possible to add a divider between `cut`,`copy` and `paste` in `cq:action:copy` move of editConfig ?

Answer (score 0):

Between most actions a dash can be inserted that gets transformed into a divider:

```
cq:actions="[text:My Component,-,edit,delete,-,copymove,-,insert]"
```

This will have a divider after "My Component" and after "Delete".
`copymove` stands for "Cut" and "Copy", so no divider between them.
 `insert` is either "New..." or "Paste", later if something is in the clipboard, also no divider possible between those two.

Here is the full documentation:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/developing/components/edit_config.html

Comment: actually, copymove action adds cut, copy and paste together. How do I split them apart to have a dash (-) ?

Comment: you Can't split cut, copy paste. If you really do so, feel free to customize edit bar actions.